jaxb2-maven-plugin cannot generate enums
I have an xsd file, and using jaxb2-maven-plugin ver 3.2.0 to generate java classes.
But the enums are not generated, even I tried it in the bindings file.
Here the excerpt of the xsd file
<xs:element name="action">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xXX-0058:actionType">
<xs:enumeration value="1">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Neue Nachricht</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Message nouveau</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="it">Nuovo messaggio</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="3">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Widerruf</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Révocation</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="it">Revoca</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="5">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Anfrage</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Demande</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="it">Domanda</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
<xs:enumeration value="6">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="de">Antwort</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="fr">Réponse</xs:documentation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="it">Risposta</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:enumeration>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

my bindings.xjb
 <jaxb:globalBindings
        generateIsSetMethod="true"
        fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true"
        typesafeEnumBase="xXX-0058:actionType"
        typesafeEnumMemberName="generateName">
    <xjc:serializable uid="-1" />
 </jaxb:globalBindings>

What do I miss and what to expect with those multiple languages?
How the enum will look like?
Where should I expect the enumeration generated? in the xsd's java class or in the xXX-058 class?
Tried with the bindings too
xXX-0058:actionType
<xs:simpleType name="actionType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="2"/>
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="9"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>


What is the xXX-0058:actionType type ? could you add it in the question ?

@LaurentSchoelens, xXX-0058:actionType added.
